# System logs written to an NFS mount

Tags: linux, mount, logging, amazon-web-services, nfs

Today we had an issue with a Linux server that filled (100%) it's entire root (`/`) partition due to a misconfiguration in postfix that led to a huge `/var/log/syslog` file and yesterday we started using AWS' EFS (NFS service) for other use case.

Based on these two events we had an internal talk about the possible workarounds for avoiding server/disk outages due to log files going crazy and, it seems to us like using a single NFS mount for all servers' log files might be a good idea as AWS' EFS service provides a virtually limitless (8 Exabytes reported by `df`) and consolidating all logs in a single drive might even ease debugging failures.

Given the above facts and idea, the question is quite obvious: is this suggested approach, of using NFS mount for all Linux logs, a good one? Pros / Cons?

I'm aware that this might be an oppinionated question, but that's not the feedback I need, but actual possible drawbacks that we might encounter based on real life facts / issues / measurements.

Answer (score 3):

1) It of course depends on the amount of logging, but network logging is slow, and this can drastically slow down parts of your system, compared to logging on local disk. NFS can also use significant CPU. I have seen people chasing performance problems for weeks on a server until they figured out that it came from logs moved to a network FS due to lack of disk space (and this was a NFS in the same machine room).

2) Better to 1) move the logs to their own partition, 2) have a rather aggressive rolling policy, and 3) then perhaps move the compressed logs to AWS. Logs can reveal a lot if compromised, so you better encrypt them before exporting them or have very tight security around your AWS storage.

Comment: Sound a good option to use extra partitions, but I have a doubt regarding their use: is fs nounting the very first thing to happen upon linux booting? i don’t think so and, I guess some log files/entries might get hidden of mounting another partition in /var/log. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: You don't need to make /var/log itself a new partition. You can use soft links in /var/log to move /var/log/postfix or whatever to another partition.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good, but what if I wanted to move files like syslog or messages to a new partition? Those are written from the very begining of Linux startup, I guess some lines even before mounting other partitions

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez to answer your long unanswered qq: a common Unix setup is to keep the root FS as small as possible and as immutable as possible, and /usr, /var, /home, /opt would be on separate partitions. The reasons for doing this have fallen away somewhat over the years (/usr is no longer "huge", comparatively, and FSs are far more resilient to failure)... but limiting the impact of disk-full conditions is still with us! It's totally ok to put /var on a separate partition. Here: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/ch03s02.en.html

Comment: @SusanW this is and has been common practice and I agree with you.  GonzaloVasquez mounting the rootfs happens after the kernel is loaded into memory and other drivers, do you have concern about a particular subsystem?

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez is correct.  I realize this is an "old" question, but it is important to note. We have an rsyslog collector that is using NFS-mounted storage for log consolidation.  One challenge with this configuration is that the NFS mount only appears late in the boot process.  We have split the rsyslog configuration to log the server itself to a local (non-NFS) /var partition, and listen to the remote feed, logging it to a separate NFS mount.  When the server reboots, we need to restart rsyslog after the NFS mount is made, or the log stream will appear under the NFS mount point and fill /.